# Why are the swing components resized using a different computer/screen?

Tags: java, swing, jar, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

a few years back I've created an executable jar file utilizing swing components.
Now I've been attempting to run that jar file on a different computer. To my surprise some swing components (e.g. `JSlider`, `JTextArea`, `JFormattedTextField`) appear "squished" while everything looks still fine on the old computer using that same jar file. I went back to the code and noticed that resizing (enlarging) the `JFrame` makes all swing components regain their desired sizes.

A few details about that program:

- The JFrame has a fixed size (`setSize(width,height)`) and cannot be resized (`setResizable(false)`)
- The components were arranged inside a `BorderLayout` using a `GridBagLayout`
- The sizes for the named swing components were dealth with using `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height))`

I hope this is helpful, otherwise feel free to ask for additional information.

As I'm just getting back into coding I was wondering: why does this happen and how can I avoid this problem in future projects so that swing components keep their size independent from the resolution/screen/computer? Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Java each machine have. You might notice that the text in a `JLabel` or something else is blurred on the older machine if your java version if older. Below Java 9, the scaling behaviour for high-DPI is not the same. If the Java version is indeed the reason for your issue, take a look at this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display).

Comment: Im using Java 8 on both machines. Thanks for the reference, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: “The sizes for the named swing components were dealth with using `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height))`” And that is likely the problem.  Swing components already calculate their own preferred size, based on the font metrics of the desktop where they’re running.  You undermined that.  Do not set the preferred size of any component.  And use `pack()` to set the frame’s size.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick responses, that was really helpful!

Comment: Adding to VGR's advice, `setResizable(false)` should be done *before*  `JFrame.pack();` but after all components are added. Making a frame a fixed size will remove some of the 'chrome' the OS puts at the sides and bottom of a resizable frame - it can `pack()` smaller. And a tip: Add @VGR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.